# Problem with Quartus's RTL viewer with viewing ROM module

Tags: vhdl, quartus

the following is my ROM implementation:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.all;

ENTITY Program_Memory IS
    port 
    (   
        add             : in std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
        instruction     : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
    );

end Program_Memory;

architecture behave of Program_Memory is

    -- Build a 2-D array type for the rom
    subtype data_word is std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    type memory_array is array(0 to (2**8-1)) of data_word;

    -- Declare the rom
    signal rom : memory_array;

begin
    instruction <= rom(to_integer(unsigned(add)));
END behave;
```

now my problem is how the RTL viewer in Quartus displays it:
[image]

it doesn't recognize it as a ROM module...

Comment: Your ROM appears to have no contents, hence can be reduced to the RTL viewer you have shown. Also, a ROM would usually be synchronous.